# Which font does the Genz-Ryan logo use?

Tags: fonts

[image: Genz-Ryan]

http://www.flickr.com/photos/90769238@N04/8244823596/

Please help me either identify this font from the Genz-Ryan logo.

Comment: I wonder if it was always so heavily slanted... kinda looks like it might have been designed to be straight. Maybe try artificially straightening it, then running it through whatthefont again?

Comment: Hi. I don't think this is a font.  The two letter Ns are different. I suspect it was hand drawn lettering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the [company history](https://www.genzryan.com/company/) "Established in 1950. Family-owned and operated since 1950", the stylistic similarities with [other logos from that period](http://www.flickr.com/photos/depressionpress/sets/72157604245013731/), the [commonness of hand-lettering from that period](http://typophile.com/node/14964#comment-86070), and the lack of results from [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), I strongly suspect that logo to be a custom typeface.

Answer (score 1):

The closest match seems to be:[Feosa Italic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/intellecta/feosa/italic/).

[image]

You can always submit your font to "What the Font" by [myfonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) and if the automatic recognition doesn't work for you, try posting it to the "What the Font Forum"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Thats close, but no cigar. I have forum posts in: MyFonts, dafont, WhatFontIs.com, Typophile and Flicker

Answer (score -2):

It is a **modified** *v*ersion of Gua*v*a Crystal Italic! See it at https://www.whatfontis.com/CR_Guava-Crystal-Italic-otf-400.font?text=GenzRyan

Comment: This doesn't look to be a match at all